# How to change color of a cell in Excel file with Iron Python?

Tags: excel, ironpython, excel-interop

How do I change cell background color in Excel from Iron Python?

I tried following code:

```
def rgb_to_hex(rgb):
    strValue = '%02x%02x%02x' % rgb
    iValue = int(strValue, 16)
    return iValue

worksheet.range["H6"].interior.color = rgb_to_hex((255,255,0))
```

But does not work. It is giving HResult error

Comment: I think `color` expects a Long RGB value, not hex

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Iron Python, but in C# I do the following:

```
Range colorCells = WS.get_Range(WS.Cells[row.Row, locCol], WS.Cells[row.Row, locCol + locWid]);
colorCells.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(color);
```

My guess is that Tim has the right suggestion, you need to use a different way to convert your RGB to a color that interior.color can accept.

In my C#, it is assigning the color as an int.

```
public static int ToOle(Color c);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to enter the color in two ways:

1. Using ColorIndex

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.colorindex

```html
worksheet.Range["H6"].Interior.ColorIndex = 3
```

2. With System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(color), like **Owen Ivory** suggested

```html
clr.AddReference('System.Drawing')
from System.Drawing import Color, ColorTranslator
    
def rgbForExcel(r, g, b):
  return ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.FromArgb(r, g, b))

worksheet.Range["H6"].Interior.Color = rgbForExcel(255, 50, 0)
```